# How SOAP sending XML to server

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I am building some bridge between SOAP and REST webservice. In other words we doesn't support SOAP anymore but clients are lazy to hire someone who create all webservices in REST for them.

So I am trying to make some "bridge" which take XML , parse it to JSON and send it to actual REST webservice.

Only thing that client will do is that he is able to change endopoint of this webservice.

What I did is at start is that I create some really simple parser in PHP.

```
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_GET);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("xml/UploadTask.xml");

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "item" );
foreach( $items as $item )
{
  $keys = $item->getElementsByTagName( "key" );
  $key = $keys->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $values = $item->getElementsByTagName( "value" );
  $value = $values->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo "$key - $value";    
}
```

I try to test it via SOAP UI so I send real soap REQUEST on new ENDPOINT
Problem is that i don't know how to get data which come from client to it, I checked HEADERs, $_POST, $_GET but that XML is nowhere.

Can someone explain me how this SOAP transfer data to server? Or is there any workaround for my situation?

Thank you I will really appriciate any advise in this situation

Comment: The **SOAPClient** encodes the data of the method-call as XML and sends the XML document via a HTTP request to the SOAP-Server. So the answer to your question might be: ***HTTP***. Could you please elaborate what you mean by *transfer* in your question?

Comment: And for your use-case, you can just make the SOAP service one method that takes one parameter that is the REST request as JSON. Done. ;)